# OR operator in WHERE clause with Arel in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

The following code constructed a valid `where` clause with an `OR` operator in Rails 4.1

```
MyModel.where(
  MyModel.where(attribute1: 1, attribute2: 2).where_values.reduce(:or)
)
```

Which is roughly equivalent to the SQL

```
select * from my_models where (attribute1 = 1 OR attribute2 = 2)
```

In Rails 4.2, the same code generates an SQL query with missing values for it's bind parameters

```
select * from my_models where attribute1 =  OR attribute2 =
```

... and generates an error due to the missing values for the bound values.

What is the equivalent code in **Rails 4.2** to generate a valid query with an OR operator?

**Edit:**

The solution requires an `Arel::Nodes::Node` derived object to be used so that it can itself be combined with other conditions via AND and OR groupings.

```
rel = MyModel.where(attribute1: 1, attribute2: 2)
conditions = [rel.where_values.reduce(:or).to_sql, *rel.bind_values.map(&:last)]

MyModel.where(conditions)
```

The `conditions` var must be a derivative of `Arel::Nodes::Node`.  The above solution works for simple queries, but for more complicated queries, `conditions` must be an Arel Node to be passed to a final query method.

Comment: where_values was removed from Rails 4.2 ... at least when I search the APIs I can find it in 3.x but not in 4.2. That may well be the source of your issue.

Comment: where_values is part of the private API in Rails 4.2... it still exists.  The bind values are in bind_values... also private.  The recent changes to Arel via AdequateRecord are the cause for the issue.

Comment: Ok, good deal. Was not 100% certain since it was 'removed' from the public API (hence the comment v. answer).

Comment: What does `Model.where(conditions).where_values.reduce(:or).to_sql` return?

Comment: `"(attribute1 = ? OR attribute2 = ?)"`

Comment: [May be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31096009/3444240)

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the below until rails 5 is out (in rails 5 AR supports `.or`):

```
ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain.class_eval do
  def or(*scopes)
    scopes_where_values = []
    scopes_bind_values  = []
    scopes.each do |scope|
      case scope
      when ActiveRecord::Relation
        scopes_where_values += scope.where_values
        scopes_bind_values += scope.bind_values
      when Hash
        temp_scope = @scope.model.where(scope)
        scopes_where_values += temp_scope.where_values
        scopes_bind_values  += temp_scope.bind_values
      end
    end
    scopes_where_values = scopes_where_values.inject(:or)
    @scope.where_values += [scopes_where_values]
    @scope.bind_values  += scopes_bind_values
    @scope
  end
end
```

With the above you can do:

```
MyModel.where.or(attribute1: 1, attribute2: 2)
# or
MyModel.where.or(MyModel.where(some conditions), MyModel.where(some other conditions))
```

Comment: Where do i define the where chain method?

Comment: where do I put this?

Comment: For anyone reading this and still at rails 4+. This goes as an initializer, it's a monkey patch

Answer (score 3):

Using raw arel might be a better option:

```
t = MyModel.arel_table
MyModel.where(
  t[:attribute1].eq(1).or(
    t[:attribute2].eq(2)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

More correctly solution based on @bsd answer, but allow arbitrary scopes on input

```ruby
 ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain.class_eval do
   def or(*scopes)
     scopes_where_values = []
     scopes_bind_values  = []
     scopes.each do |scope|
       case scope
       when ActiveRecord::Relation
         scopes_where_values << scope.where_values.reduce(:and)
         scopes_bind_values += scope.bind_values
       when Hash
         temp_scope = @scope.model.where(scope)
         scopes_where_values << temp_scope.where_values.reduce(:and)
         scopes_bind_values  += temp_scope.bind_values
       end
     end
     scopes_where_values = scopes_where_values.inject(:or)
     @scope.where_values += [scopes_where_values]
     @scope.bind_values  += scopes_bind_values
     @scope
   end
 end
```

P.S. Previous code by @bsd can't correctly work in little difficult case:
User.where.or(User.where(rating: 3), User.where(startups: { progress: 100, rating: nil })

Result of old code is wrong:

> SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (("startups"."rating" = 3 OR "startups"."progress" = 100) OR "startups"."rating" IS NULL)

Changed code generate correct:

> SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("startups"."rating" = 3 OR "startups"."progress" = 100 AND "startups"."rating" IS NULL)