# ActiveRecord OR query Hash notation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I know there are 3 main notations for supplying arguments to the [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) ActiveRecord method:

1. Pure String
2. Array
3. Hash

Specifying `and` for the `where` method is straight forward:

```ruby
# Pure String notation
Person.where("name = 'Neil' AND age = 27")

# Array notation
Person.where(["name = ? AND age = ?", 'Neil', 27])

# Hash notation
Person.where({name: "Neil", age: 27})
```

Specifying `or` for this same `where` method is stumping me for the hash syntax. Is it possible?

```ruby
# Pure String notation
Person.where("name = 'Neil' OR age = 27")

# Array notation
Person.where(["name = ? OR age = ?", 'Neil', 27])

# Hash notation DOESN'T WORK
Person.where({name: "Neil" OR age: 27})
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

There are 5 options that could be considered as implementations of «Hash notation» (the last two are kinda hash-*ish*):

1. With Ruby on Rails 5 you are able to do the following chaining using [`ActiveRecord::Relation#or`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) method:

   ```
   Person.where(name: 'Neil').or(Person.where(age: 27))
   ```
2. Use [`where_values`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.2.8/ActiveRecord%2FQueryMethods%3Awhere_values) together with [`reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). The [`unscoped`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/unscoped) method is necessary [only for Rails 4.1+](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#changes-on-default-scopes) to ensure `default_scope` is not included in the `where_values`. Otherwise predicates from both `default_scope` and `where` would be chained with the `or` operator:

   ```
   Person.where( 
     Person.unscoped.where(name: ['Neil'], age: [27]).where_values.reduce(:or) 
   )
   ```
3. Install third-party plugins that implement these or similar features, for example:

   - [Where Or](http://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or) *(backport of the Ruby on Rails 5 `.or` feature mentioned above)*
   - [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel)

     ```
     Person.where{(name == 'Neil') | (age == 27)}
     ```
   - [RailsOr](https://github.com/khiav223577/rails_or)

     ```
     Person.where(name: 'Neil').or(age: 27)
     ```
   - [ActiverecordAnyOf](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of)

     ```
     Person.where.anyof(name: 'Neil', age: 27)
     ```
   - [SmartTuple](https://github.com/dadooda/smart_tuple)

     ```
     Person.where(
       (SmartTuple.new(' or ') << {name: 'Neil', age: 27}).compile
     )
     ```
4. Use [Arel](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel):

   ```
   Person.where( 
     Person.arel_table[:name].eq('Neil').or(
       Person.arel_table[:age].eq(27)
     ) 
   )
   ```
5. Use prepared statements with named parameters:

   ```
   Person.where('name = :name or age = :age', name: 'Neil', age: 27)
   ```

Comment: This is a complete answer.  The `arel` answer is particularly good since this is what's getting added to Rails 5, as I understand.

Comment: If you can't wait for Rails 5, you can use this backport of the feature to rails 4.2. Nicely packaged up as the 'where-or' gem https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or

Comment: If your project is still in Rails 3+, you can try the rails_or gem: https://github.com/khiav223577/rails_or

Answer (score 1):

As says potashin, you can use another third-party plugins that implement this feature. I have a long time using [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) and works pretty well for this and much more features like complex subqueries or joins.

That query using squeel:

```
@people= Person.where{(name == 'Neil') | (age = 27)}
```