# How to query records that are inside date range A or date range B

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to fetch records (events) that have a date range (e.g. `event_start` and `event_end)` within a date range, so users can query all events that are between respectively inside day A and day B.

If Rails 5 would be available yet, I could use `.or`, but how to write this for Rails 4?

```
d = Date.today
Event.all.where(:date_start => d.beginning_of_week..d.end_of_week).or.where(:date_end => d.beginning_of_week..d.end_of_week)
```

**Update**

I think [arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) does the job.

Comment: [May be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31096009/3444240)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try arel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Event.all.where('date_start >= ? AND date_end < ?', event_start, event_end)
```

You will probably need to add a day to `event_end` if it is the same day as the last day of your range in order for the less than not to exclude that day, e.g.:

```
event_end + 1.days
```

Another way is to use `BETWEEN`

```
Event.all.where('date_start BETWEEN ? AND ? AND date_end BETWEEN ? AND ?', event_start, event_end, event_start, event_end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
d = Date.today
date_week = d.beginning_of_week..d.end_of_week
Event.where('date_start = ? OR date_end = ?', date_week, date_week)
```

Hope this may helpful!!