# How to chain or from Arel Array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754977/1979953.

```
user = User.arel_table

u1 = user[:id].eq(1)
u2 = user[:id].eq(2)
u3 = user[:id].eq(3)

result = User.where(u1.or(u2).or(u3))
```

is ok.

How to chain like above? use `each` or `map` etc.

```
user = User.arel_table

foo = [
  user[:id].eq(1),
  user[:id].eq(2),
  user[:id].eq(3)
]

result = foo.map{|o| ??? }
```

Comment: [You may also find this post helpful (non-string ways of constructing or queries on different columns)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31096009/3444240)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reduce`:

```
conditions = foo.reduce(:or)
User.where(conditions)
```

In your case it can be just:

```
User.where(id: [1, 2, 3])
```

Code above constructs `where id in (1, 2, 3)` query.