# Active Record - Chain Queries with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Rails: 4.1.2

Database: PostgreSQL

For one of my queries, I am using methods from both the [textacular](https://github.com/textacular/textacular) gem and Active Record. How can I chain some of the following queries with an "OR" instead of an "AND":

```
people = People.where(status: status_approved).fuzzy_search(first_name: "Test").where("last_name LIKE ?", "Test")
```

I want to chain the last two scopes (`fuzzy_search` and the `where` after it) together with an "OR" instead of an "AND." So I want to retrieve all People who are approved AND (whose first name is similar to "Test" OR whose last name contains "Test"). I've been struggling with this for quite a while, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [the following post can be related to your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31096009/3444240)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, I came up with the solution! Here's what I did:

This is the query I wanted to chain together with an OR:

```
people = People.where(status: status_approved).fuzzy_search(first_name: "Test").where("last_name LIKE ?", "Test")
```

As Hoang Phan suggested, when you look in the console, this produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT "people".*, COALESCE(similarity("people"."first_name", 'test'), 0) AS "rank69146689305952314"
FROM "people"
WHERE "people"."status" = 1 AND (("people"."first_name" % 'Test')) AND (last_name LIKE 'Test')  ORDER BY "rank69146689305952314" DESC
```

I then dug into the textacular gem and found out how the rank is generated. I found it in the [textacular.rb](https://github.com/textacular/textacular/blob/master/lib/textacular.rb#L124) file and then crafted the SQL query using it. I also replaced the "AND" that connected the last two conditions with an "OR":

```
# Generate a random number for the ordering
rank = rand(100000000000000000).to_s

# Create the SQL query
sql_query = "SELECT people.*, COALESCE(similarity(people.first_name, :query), 0)" + 
            " AS rank#{rank} FROM people" +
            " WHERE (people.status = :status AND" +
            " ((people.first_name % :query) OR (last_name LIKE :query_like)))" + 
            " ORDER BY rank#{rank} DESC"
```

I took out all of quotation marks in the SQL query when referring to tables and fields because it was giving me error messages when I kept them there and even if I used single quotes.

Then, I used the [find_by_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql) method to retrieve the `People` object IDs in an array. The symbols (`:status`, `:query`, `:query_like`) are used to protect against SQL injections, so I set their values accordingly:

```
# Retrieve all the IDs of People who are approved and whose first name and last name match the search query.
# The IDs are sorted in order of most relevant to the search query.
people_ids = People.find_by_sql([sql_query, query: "Test", query_like: "%Test%", status: 1]).map(&:id)
```

I get the IDs and not the `People` objects in an array because `find_by_sql` returns an `Array` object and not a `CollectionProxy` object, as would normally be returned, so I cannot use ActiveRecord query methods such as `where` on this array. Using the IDs, we can execute another query to get a `CollectionProxy` object. However, there's one problem: If we were to simply run `People.where(id: people_ids)`, the order of the IDs would not be preserved, so all the relevance ranking we did was for nothing.

Fortunately, there's a nice gem called [order_as_specified](https://github.com/panorama-ed/order_as_specified) that will allow us to retrieve all `People` objects in the specific order of the IDs. Although the gem would work, I didn't use it and instead wrote a short line of code to craft conditions that would preserve the order.

```
order_by = people_ids.map { |id| "people.id='#{id}' DESC" }.join(", ")
```

If our `people_ids` array is `[1, 12, 3]`, it would create the following ORDER statement:

```
"people.id='1' DESC, people.id='12' DESC, people.id='3' DESC"
```

I learned from [this comment](https://gist.github.com/cpjolicoeur/3590737#gistcomment-1409093) that writing an ORDER statement in this way would preserve the order.

Now, all that's left is to retrieve the `People` objects from ActiveRecord, making sure to specify the order.

```
people = People.where(id: people_ids).order(order_by)
```

And that did it! I didn't worry about removing any duplicate IDs because ActiveRecord does that automatically when you run the `where` command.

I understand that this code is not very portable and would require some changes if any of the `people` table's columns are modified, but it works perfectly and seems to execute only one query according to the console.

Answer (score 0):

I digged into fuzzy_search and saw that it will be translated to something like:

```
SELECT "people".*, COALESCE(similarity("people"."first_name", 'test'), 0) AS "rankxxx" 
FROM "people" 
WHERE (("people"."first_name" % 'abc'))  
ORDER BY "rankxxx" DESC
```

That says if you don't care about preserving order, it will just filter the result by `WHERE (("people"."first_name" % 'abc'))`

Knowing that and now you can simply write the query with similar functionality:

```
People.where(status: status_approved)
      .where('(first_name % :key) OR (last_name LIKE :key)', key: 'Test')
```

In case you want order, please specify what would you like the order will be after joining 2 conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is very helpful! I would prefer to use hash conditions in the query, as they are neater and easier to modify, but if I have to, I will use the raw SQL. `fuzzy_search` orders the results from most relevant to least relevant using a "rankxxx" field. However, the "xxx" part after "rank" seems to be a unique number (maybe a timestamp) each time the query is run. Do you know how I would order the results by "rankxxx"?

Comment: I'd rather say you cannot, the reason why the gem using random numbers is to prevent anybody from using it later on. You could use the same select as theirs (says `COALESCE(similarity ...) AS <your variable>`), but it is not recommended. And you will face a trouble when evaluating the 2 conditions. If you care about order in this case, the best bet would be to select 2 times with activerecord, then aggregate the results whatever you want. You know it's not that much of a performance penalty, and easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't believe performing two queries would help because I would not get the rank ordering. The results from the first query would be the only ones that will be ordered by rank. I have copied the query that is generated and modified it so that it would work with the `find_by_sql` method. I added in variable escapes to protect against SQL injection. My only problem now is that, with the raw SQL, I am not getting unique records. I have tried adding the DISTINCT keyword after the SELECT statement to no avail.

Comment: I have it working! I would prefer to get the DISTINCT keyword working, but for now I am using the `uniq` method to filter out any duplicate records after the query has completed. I will post my answer within the next couple of days. I basically had to use raw SQL, as much as I didn't want to.