# ActiveRecord OR query (multiple conditions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I create an ActiveRecord query without using a SQL string in Rails to get something like:

```
books = Book.where(author: 1, **from_day: [1,5] or to_day: [1,5]**)
```

Comment: Just to clarify -- what is meant by `[1,5]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveRecord OR query Hash notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096009/activerecord-or-query-hash-notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
books = Book.where(author: 1).where("from_day IN (?) or to_day IN (?)", [1,5],[1,5])
```