# ActiveRecord OR query for daterange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to get books ActiveRecord objects that have a 'from or 'to' between a date range `(start_date..end_date)`.

This code works just fine:

```
Book.where(from: start_date..end_date)
```

But I want to use 'or' in my statement and this code fails:

```
Book.where("from: ? OR to: ?", (start_date..end_date), (start_date..end_date))
```

Please help me to find my mistake.

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: [May be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31096009/3444240)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
Book.where("books.from BETWEEN ? AND ? OR books.to BETWEEN ? AND ?", start_date,end_date,start_date,end_date)
```

Comment: It is almost right. I get SELECT `books`.* FROM `books` WHERE (from BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-29' OR to BETWEEN '2016-02-01' AND '2016-02-29'). But a little part is still missing (should be `books`.`from` BETWEEN ... AND ...)

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) on Range conditions:

```
Client.where(created_at: (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight)
```

That will produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.created_at BETWEEN '2008-12-21 00:00:00' AND '2008-12-22 00:00:00')
```

So given in you can use [`or` in ActiveRecord in the Rails 5](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or), you can do

```
Book.where(from: start_date..end_date).or(Book.where(from: new_start_date..new_end_date))
```

Notes: You don't need to use rails 5 to use this `OR` query. We can also used it with `rails 4.2`, thanks to  gem [where-or](https://github.com/Eric-Guo/where-or)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if from < to
    Book.where("from >= #{start_date} OR to  <= #{end_date}")
 else 
  // do something else
 end
```

Comment: 'from' should be less than 'end_date' & 'to' should' be bigger than 'start_date' too, I explained it in my question

Comment: you can define a check to do this