# Chain Scopes as OR Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In model:

```
 scope :verified, -> { where(verified: true)}
 scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
```

Now, `Model.active.verified` results as `active and verified`. How can I chain scopes as `OR`? Please note that I don't want to combine both scopes as one like:
`where("active = ? OR verified = ?", true, true)`

Comment: If you don't want to do it like `where("active = ? OR verified = ?", true, true)`, then I think you have to wait for *Rails 5* in which `ActiveRecord` uses `.or` operator. So you can combine the scopes like `Model.active.or.verified`

Comment: I am curious to know, is there any particular reason to not to use or query?

Comment: There are more than 10 scopes and they are used conditionally. So if i use it in that way, I will have to write many permutation-combination cases.

Comment: As you said I will have to wait for rails 5, how will it be written in rails 5?

Comment: Ok. In rails 5 Its like, Model.active.or(Model.verified)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to upgrade to Rails 5 in order to use `or`. There are ways of doing that in Rails 4. Although these do not lend themselves very well for being used in chained scopes, you can achieve similar level of convenience in building up your criterias.

1. Arel tables. Arel is ActiveRecord's underlying implementation of relational algebra. It does support `or` among other powerful things.

   ```
   arel_table = Model.arel_table

   Model.where(
     arel_table[:active].eq(true).
     or(
       arel_table[:verified].eq(true)
     )
   )

   # => SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE ("models"."active" = 't' OR "models"."verified" = 't')
   ```

As you can see, chaining criteria is complicated by the fact the `or` has to be applied inside `where`. Criteria could be built externally before passing to `where` but again, their hierarchical structure makes it less straightforward.

2. Monkeypatching ActiveRecord, adding `or` implementation. Put this into **config/initializers/active_record.rb**:

   ```
   ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain.class_eval do
     def or(*scopes)
       scopes_where_values = []
       scopes_bind_values  = []
       scopes.each do |scope|
         case scope
         when ActiveRecord::Relation
           scopes_where_values += scope.where_values
           scopes_bind_values += scope.bind_values
         when Hash
           temp_scope = @scope.model.where(scope)
           scopes_where_values += temp_scope.where_values
           scopes_bind_values  += temp_scope.bind_values
         end
       end
       scopes_where_values = scopes_where_values.inject(:or)
       @scope.where_values += [scopes_where_values]
       @scope.bind_values  += scopes_bind_values
       @scope
     end
   end
   ```

With this you will be able to do `or` queries like this:

```
Model.where.or(verified: true, active: true)

# => SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE ("models"."verified" = $1 OR "models"."active" = $2)  [["verified", "t"], ["active", "t"]]
```

You can add more criteria like so:

```
Model.where.or(verified: true, active: true, other: false)
```

The query can be put in a class method like this:

```
def self.filtered(criteria)
  where.or(criteria)    # This is chainable!
end
```

or in scope, which is basically the same:

```
scope :filtered, lambda { |criteria| where.or(criteria) }
```

Since `criteria` is just a hash, you can build it in a convenient way with as many elements as you like:

```
criteria = {}
criteria[:verified] = true if include_verified?
criteria[:active] = true if include_active?
...

Model.filtered(criteria).where(... more criteria ...)
```

And there you have it. Read for more details these SO questions:

[ActiveRecord Arel OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976358/activerecord-arel-or-condition)

[OR operator in WHERE clause with Arel in Rails 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627390/or-operator-in-where-clause-with-arel-in-rails-4-2)

Finally, in case you are not opposed to third-party solutions, take a look at the [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) gem.